# Install SSH for Git on Windows 7

Tags: git, ssh

I am trying to setup SSH for git on my Windows 7 system. Unfortunately according to
`ssh -v`
I do not have ssh installed.

I installed git using the Windows download from http://git-scm.com/ (mySysGit I think). According to [this](http://www.slideshare.net/julienbarbier42/install-git-with-ssh-on-windows-7) tutorial I should have gotten a dialogue about installing OpenSSH but I did not. I have googled a tonne but not come up with any luck, - it seems like it always gets installed with the installer.

I have also tried installed GitHub for Windows but this did not fix the issue either.

Anyone able to explain where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Git Bash](http://git-scm.com/downloads), you should get everything you need.
Which options did you choose during the installation ?

Comment: Installed with options of 'run using git-bash only' and use the line endings for multiple platforms. I never received a dialogue for SSH. I installed the most recent stable Git-1.9.5-preview20141217.exe?

Comment: I just tried to reinstall the client, with the newest version.
http://nsa33.casimages.com/img/2015/01/25/150125122113760101.png

I let all default settings, and seems to be great.

Have you unistalled all previous version before install another one ?

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled with this latest version, - still no option to install OpenSSH. Still not installed when run ssh -v. I will try download an older version of git

Comment: But that screenshot doesn't show SSH as being installed does it? I thought it should give you the version number like this? http://snag.gy/J8MFr.jpg  Secondly, if I run the list command it says there is no directory? http://snag.gy/A5TQf.jpg

Comment: Okay, so I just went ahead and starting using SSH commands and it appears that it is in fact installed, despite these replies in git bash, I just haven't set up an identity yet *slaps forehead*. Thanks Bart